# is there a pastebin service that supports terminal escape sequences?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

Is there a pastebin service that supports colors? I understand some of them have syntax hilighting, but I'd like to do arbitrary coloring, preferably using the terminal escape sequences.

For example, I'd like to do:

```
grep --color=force foo /etc/motd | pastebinit
```

Does anyone know such a cool site?

Comment: Try the ones I documented in this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108493/easy-way-to-paste-command-line-output-to-paste-bin-services/108494#108494

Comment: I'd be also interested in one supported by wgetpaste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Termbin.com](http://termbin.com) supports what you need.

```
$ grep --color=force foo /etc/motd | nc termbin.com 9999
http://termbin.com/xxxx

$ curl http://termbin.com/xxxx
```

You'll get exactly what you sent.

The service is running on a free and open software called [Fiche](https://github.com/solusipse/fiche) so you can also install your own.

Comment: that's pretty awesome! too bad the pastes aren't rendered on the web though.... but yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: "Life span of single paste is one month. Older pastes are deleted." — beware if you expect long-term hosting.

Comment: This answer is technically correct - you will get exactly what you sent - but it means that you will see the ANSI codes, not the colors...

Answer (score 6):

pastebinit isn't satisfactory.

You can convert ascii/ansi to HTML via the 'aha' (ANSI HTML Adapter) command.

```
sudo apt-get install aha || sudo yum install aha
ls --color m* -d | aha
```

Unfortunately - you can't just pipe that HTML into pastebinit.  You could host the HTML temporarily if various firewalls permit it:

```
mkdir /tmp/temphosting
ls --color m* -d | aha > /tmp/temphosting/cmd.html
cd /tmp/temphosting
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then point a web browser to http://ip.or.host.name:8000/cmd.html

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a new service I just found out about called [asciinema.org](https://asciinema.org/) which provides on-screen recording facilities. It is not a pastebin, but it is probably the best approximation of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this pastebin that appears to support ANSI colors with Unicode chars!

Seems that it was specifically designed for old school BBS Unicode ANSI color artwork... check it out:

http://paste.sixteencolors.net/6

Comment: Seems to be gone.

Comment: Good catch!  Looks like that link gives a `502 Bad Gateway` error currently.  It would appear that something changed, and `paste.sixteencolors.net` no longer is a working URL.  Seems that `http://sixteencolors.net/` still gives a page that works, however I can't find the pastebin functionality anymore.  Seems that they have a web page where you can [create ANSI Art here](http://draw.sixteencolors.net/try/)

Comment: Both link in this answer and the links in the comment above give 404s as of writing these words.

Comment: Yeah, sadly this site has gone away :-(